# (1054)Unknown column in 'field list' - Mysql Error

Tags: mysql, field

I'm try to update some coloumn's cell in mysql.

when i execute this , value as number:

```
update tablename set contents=1 where contensid=218;
```

it is working.

but i execute value as a character:

`update tablename set contents=text where contensid=218;`

> Please try again later or contact an Administrator. (1054)Unknown
>   column 'text' in 'field list'

what i have to do update value as character ??

Comment: since `text` is string, you should wrap it with single quote. `contents='text'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't put your "text" inside '', query thinks it is a column in your table. So do this:

```
update tablename set contents='text' where contensid=218;
```

Comment: Or single quotes (apostrophes)

Comment: Simple and straight (Y)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your column is wrong,You will need check the column,and again comit.

Comment: This should be a comment!